# How to change a property on runtime wix

Tags: wix, custom-action

Suppose I am using a directory name as

```
<Property Id="PROJECTNAME"> xyz </Property>

<Directory Id="Hello" Name=[PROJECTNAME]>
```

And I want to change the directory name at the time of running the installer.

The directory name should be passed from command line or read from a file.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks In Advance,
Pradeep Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two cases:

1. **Parameter is passed through command line**.

   Here you can use the feature of the MSI package and pass your parameter as property for  example **REALINSTALLDIRECTORY**="C:\Install".
2. **Parameter is passed through the file.**

   You should implement the custom action that will read the value from the file and set the **REALINSTALLDIRECTORY** property.

After that you can use the custom action to explicitly set the directory:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetDirectoryToValue" Directory="Hello" Value="[REALINSTALLDIRECTORY]" />
```

This Custom action is executed like this:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="SetDirectoryToValue" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```